# How to use group sequence on form type in symfony forms?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8, symfony-validator

The idea is to first validate if all the required fields are not blank. If all the required data is provided then validate if the values entered are correct. The usual case for groups sequence. How ever when I apply `new GroupSequence(["Basic", "Strict"])` to the `validation_groups` option it turns out the form to be valid even if all the fields are blank. If `validation_groups` value is set to `["Basic", "Strict"]` the form is validated properly but with all constraints, and that is not what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add("name", null, [
                    "constraints" => new NotBlank(["groups" => ["Basic"]])
                ])
                ->add("phone", MyPhoneType::class, [
                    "constraints" => [
                        new NotBlank(["groups" => ["Basic"]]),
                        new PhoneNumber(["groups" => ["Strict"])
                    ]
                ])
                ->add("email", EmailType::class, [
                    "constraints" => [
                        new NotBlank(["groups" => ["Basic"]]),
                        new Email(["groups" => ["Strict"]]),
                    ],
                ])
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            "validation_groups" => new GroupSequence(["Basic", "Strict"])
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with putting the GroupSequence mapping in the form data class object? (your `User` entity or any `DTO`?) I can't find any reference in the documentation for using it directly in the form (Or do you have any link to your usage).

Comment: Did you try  it like that "validation_groups" => ['Default',"Basic", "Strict"] ?

Comment: @goto, no DTO's nor entities are available and are needless in this project. The Forms and Validation components are working standalone outside of Symfony standard distribution.

Comment: @Filchev, yes - same result.

Comment: But for me it should be an option named `group_sequence` or something like that, because `validations_group` is just totally different. Do you find any reference of what you are using?

Comment: theres a bug opened for it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22373

Answer (score 0):

> ## What am I doing wrong?

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22373) of Symfony version 2.8 and is fixed newer versions.

But I also did not see any documentation which shows that you can use a `GroupSequence` when configue the `validation_groups` option.

I would assume that when using Symfony 2.8 a [custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) which takes care of all validation is the best choice of handling such a situation.